# After SSH tunneling into localhost:6688 I get "site can`t be reached - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nodes, chainlink

I finally decided to run a chainlink node on kovan, so I followed this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9Uknfw27IU&list=LL&index=8&t=555s on how to set up the node and after a few hours of work I made it happen. So after SSH tunneling into localhost:6688 I got the GUI for the chainlink operator and wrote in the password and got in.

So the next day I decided to program some jobs on the node and did the same thing as last day and got the
site can`t be reached - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when SSH tunneling in localhost:6688 and I can see that the CL node is running in the linux box with no errors and note I dont own a router.

What I tried so far:

-switching browsers

-temporarily disabled the windows firewall

-manually opening up the port 6688

-deleting the VM instance on Google cloud platform and creating a new one

-double checking the .env file if  database and other info from GCP and infuras
WSS were correct

-check the proxy settings

-cleared browser history and cookies

-deleted Winsock catalog entries

None of this has helped to resolve this issue, any help or suggestions would really be appreciated...

Comment: Managed to fix the issue myself, If anyone has the same error try this: go to your GCP and go to VM istances - firewall and add an exception for port 6688, then copy the externalIP , add it as your localhost= externalIP :6688...worked for me.

Comment: Awesome! Could you please add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the issue myself, If anyone has the same error try this: go to your GCP and go to VM istances - firewall and add an exception for port 6688, then copy the externalIP , add it as your localhost= externalIP :6688...worked for me.